# AdWhirl Implementation error

Tags: iphone, xcode, adwhirl

I have a blank xcode document and trie to implement AdWhirl, when I buld it, I have this errors.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper scheduleInCurrentRunLoop] in AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper unscheduleFromCurrentRunLoop] in AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper initWithHostname:callbackDelegate:] in AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper initWithHostname:callbackDelegate:] in AWNetworkReachabilityWrapper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I need some help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `SystemConfiguration.framework`. Add it, and check that you have the other required frameworks too.

From the [AdWhirl iOS SDK Setup Instructions](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/ios/AdWhirliOSSDKSetup.html):

> Add the system frameworks required by
>   the supported ad networks:
>
> ```
> AddressBook
> AudioToolbox
> AVFoundation
> CoreLocation
> libsqlite3
> libz
> MapKit
> ```
>
> The following additional frameworks are required by the iAd adapter:
>
> ```
> iAd
> QuartzCore
> SystemConfiguration
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add The "SystemConfiguration.framework" framework from existing framework.